# How do you configure Orchard CMS to to use the default (empty) subdomain?

Tags: orchardcms, subdomain, domain-name

I've got Orchard CMS running on `www.example.com` but I also want it to pick up requests to `example.com` (no subdomain).

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a permanent redirect from one to the other. That's the right thing to do for SEO.